# How to make horizontal bar graph label values as hyperlink using google chart api

Tags: google-visualization

```
 var options = {
```

May be vAxis have some properties for making label value as hyperlink

```
                     vAxis: { textStyle: { color: '#005500', fontSize: '13', fontName:  'Arial'} },
                     width: 700,
                     height: 400,
                     bar: { groupWidth: '15%' },
                     isStacked: true,
                     chartArea: { left: 150, width: 700 }

                 };
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot create hyperlinks from the axis labels, but you can use a "click" event handler for your chart that detects clicks on the axis labels and then acts as if a link was clicked:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'click', function (e) {
    // match the id of the axis label
    var match = e.targetID.match(/hAxis#0#label#(\d+)/);
    if (match && match.length) {
        var row = parseInt(match[1]);
        // use row to fetch any data you need from the DataTable to construct your hyperlink, eg:
        var label = data.getValue(row, 0);
        // then construct your URL and use it however you want, eg:
        var url = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=' + label;
        window.location = url;
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes..because i tried many things(i.e:'<a>'tdata.addRow()+'</a>')but didnt get success...actually when we click on text and put some event on it .other user may not understand that it is actually a link..so in my case i am calling a script function onclick event.

Comment: Got a solution....!I have just added a "onmouseover" event on labels & convert its css property cursor to pointer.so its look like a link.     .

Comment: google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseover', function () {
                    $('#id').find('svg').contents().find('g').css('cursor', 'pointer');
                });